# best option for background subtraction using emgucv?

Tags: c#-4.0, emgucv, background-subtraction

can you suggest a good option for background subtraction using emgucv? my project is real time pedestrian detection.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need this, but...in EmguCV, if you have 2 images of say type `Image<Bgr, Byte>` or any other type, called img1 and img2, doing `img1 - img2` does work! There is a function called AbsDiff as well, I think it works like this: `img1.AbsDiff(img2)`, you could look into that.

If you already have the picture of the background (img1) and you have the current frame (img2), you could do the above.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite possible take a look at the "MotionDetection" example provided with EMGU this should get you started.

Effectively the code that removes the foreground is effectively named "_forgroundDetector" it is the "_motionHistory" that presents stores what movement has occurred.

The example has everything you need if you have trouble running it let me know,

Cheer

Chris

See:[Removing background from _capture.QueryFrame()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328693/removing-background-from-capture-queryframe/7331587#7331587)